# Nested grid is not responding to rows

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Pretty confused - I am referring to the .grid2 section I've tried changing all of the classes and making them more or less specific Could this be to do with the grid wrapper on the outside? Strangely the section is going recognizing that there is a 3 column grid but not recognizing the rows (even when i define them) here is the code

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <title>Powerwashing</title>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">


      <div class="header">
        <ul>
          <li><a class="a" href="#">About us</a></li>
          <li><a class="s" href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li> <a class="l"href="#"></a><img src="wash.png" width=100px alt="Powerwashing services">
          </a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="w" href="#">Why us</a></li>
          <li><a class="c" href="#">Contact us</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
     <div class="grid2">
       <section class="se">


       <h2>Services</h2>
       <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates minus molestias quaerat laudantium. Ab nihil eius velit nisi tempora quibusdam illo animi esse provident corporis fuga, minima, numquam obcaecati ut atque molestias cum. Tenetur magni adipisci porro eum mollitia, dolor dolorem repellendus aspernatur quibusdam architecto nobis, ab cum, aliquid nulla?
       </p>
       </section>

       <section class="ab">
         <h3>About us</h3>
         <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos eligendi, dolor obcaecati. Fuga corporis aliquid possimus, deserunt earum ut quod, quia maxime, optio dolorem laudantium soluta quae omnis pariatur iusto natus veniam rerum labore tenetur veritatis eius deleniti. Qui, tempora.
         </p>

       </section>
       <section class="wh">


       <h3>Why us</h3>
       <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora nemo exercitationem maiores excepturi vero asperiores, quaerat necessitatibus. Aspernatur, veniam voluptas earum esse rerum, expedita hic in quam alias sunt laudantium quisquam ducimus iste sit iusto quaerat labore molestias saepe quo.
       </p>

       </section>
     </div>


  </div>



</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    *{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

.wrapper{
  display: grid;

}
.header ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: green;
  padding:20px;
  text-align: center;

  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5,1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
     "a s l w c";
  align-items: center;

}
.header a{
background-color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding:5px;





}
a .a{
  grid-area:a;
}
a .s{
  grid-area:s;
}
a .l{
  grid-area: l;


}
a .w{
  grid-area:w;
}
a .c{
  grid-area:c;
}
.grid2{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);

  grid-template-areas:
   "se wh wh"
   "se ab ab";
}
section .se h3 p{
  grid-area: se;
}
section .ab h3{
  grid-area: ab;
}
section .wh h3{
  grid-area: wh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that its because i was calling the section tags and each section had a seperate section tag, Im not sure why this wouldnt work though?